# Restrict the user to paste max (40 ) Characters in textarea

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc

I am restricting the user to enter a max limit(40Char) of characters in a text area.
I am Calling this below `JS` function on `onKeyUp` event of `textarea`.

But when **i copy paste a content which is more than 40chars**, not gettinng pop-up(Alert) until i do a keyup/down on the textarea.

```
function checkLength(textBox, e, maxLength) {
  if (textBox.value.length > maxLength - 1) {        
     alert("* You have reached max limit ");
     textBox.value = textBox.value.substr(0, maxLength);
  }
  else {
     alert(maxLength - textBox.value.length + " characters remaining");
  }
}
```

Is there a way to get alert without `keyup/down` after pasting into `textarea`?

Comment: What should happen with the text that was pasted if it is longer than 40 characters?

Comment: Do you use a JavaScript library for binding event handlers?

Comment: @sime It should alert("more than 40 characters entered pls revise");

Comment: I can write a solution, but I need to know how you bind event handlers in JavaScript. Do you use a library?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Got the solution guys :)

```
onKeyUp = "checkLength(this);">
</form>
<script>
function fncKeyLength(textBox){
if (window.event.ctrlKey){
if (window.event.keyCode == 86)//Paste 
if (textBox.value.length > maxLength - 1)
{            
  alert("* You have reached max limit ");
  textBox.value = textBox.value.substr(0, maxLength); 
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use the `onChange` event for that

Answer (score 1):

If you want to trim the extra characters on the fly, another possible way will be as follows.

- Create a trim function which will trim characters more than 40. for example - `trimText()`.
- onFocus - add a `setInterval` function to call `trimText()` after every 500 milli seconds.
- onBlur - clear `setInterval` function and run `trimText()` once again.
- onChange - run `trimText()` once again. This willbe an extra check, if needed.

Based on your requirement you can update the time duration.

Sample : http://jsfiddle.net/codebombs/AyLdW/

If you want to show only one alert message, then use `onchange`.

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/codebombs/3Jdvg/1/

Comment: I want to get alert once user paste more than 40 characters.. but with my code, When user paste 40 characters i m not gettuing alert. once the user click on textarea i m getting alert..

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have an asp Textbox,then we can use "OnPaste" event as shown below

```
   <asp:TextBox TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server" ID="txtComment_c" 
    onpaste="return maxLengthPaste(this, 40)" MaxLength="40"></asp:TextBox>
```

Before pasting the content first we need to check how much length was already occupied and then window.clipboard.getdata.length will give us the length of data which is about to paste.Consider the code below

```
   function maxLengthPaste(field, maxChars) {

        if ((field.value.length + window.clipboardData.getData("Text").length) > maxChars) {
            alert("Cannot have more than " + maxChars + " Characters");
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
$('#textbox1').on('change', function() {
    var currentText = $(this).val();
    if(currentText.length > 40)
        $(this).val(substr(currentText,0,40));
});
```

There's even an [Ellipsis](http://webdood.com/?p=261) plugin to add an ellipsis (...) for you.